# SQL QUERY - select 1 record on the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i use the query to filter out the rest of the records on the same date and get only 1 record.

Below is the sample database.

[image]

expected output, if same date have two records, get only the "S" value from source.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried analytical functions? Have you search for simular questions here?

Comment: What query below? You've only included an image of data (which is frowned upon, and you have enough reputation to know that); there is no SQL query.

Comment: sorry, updated.because my query is poor having error during debuging therefore i didnt post it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prioritization query.  I think `row_number()` might be the simplest solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by projectsite, convert(date, checkin) order by source desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks alot!!! i forgot about this `row_number() `! Thanks!